# Force TR height in HTML

Tags: html, css, tablerow, css-tables

I am trying to force a table row that only contains images to be the images' height, but the page always displays a few extra pixels tall.
See http://www.slamgmt.com/newsite/index.php
Also http://www.slamgmt.com/newsite/sla.css

The banner at the top uses CSS classes "banner" and "bannersidebar" all of which explicitly set the height, but the actual height is too large, as seen by the white space below the banner and above the black line.

Does anyone know a way to force it to trim that space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `display:block` to the header image, that should fix it...

```
img.topbanner
{
max-width:100%;
border:0px;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: It should really work, I tried it myself in Firebug and it works. Sure you used exactly the above code? (i edited my post)

Comment: Never mind, it was an FTP issue, the changes were not applied.  This worked.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've ever given a height to a tr, it just becomes as tall as the td within.

Also, you're defining a tr height of 192, but the td is 194, taking into account for the 2px border.

```
tr.banner
{
height:192px;
max-height:192px;
}

td.banner
{
height:192px;
max-height:192px;
border-bottom:2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I set the height on the tr and the tds inside it.  And the issue is the whitespace between the border and the image.  I had the border as the top of the cell below, and that produced an identical result.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: According to my Opera Dragonfly, the TR is displaying as 195, but is supposed to be 192.

Answer (score 0):

I believe img tags add a slight margin around them. Try setting the margin:0px on the img and see if that gets rid of your issue.